# Append two or more array to a single master array

Tags: c#, arrays, append

I am new to C# programming, I migrated from python. I want to append two or more array (exact number is not known , depends on db entry) into a single array
like the list.append method in python does. Here the code example of what I want to do

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
int[] b = {4,5,6};
int[] c = {7,8,9};
int[] d;
```

I don't want to add all the arrays at a time. I need somewhat like this

```
// I know this not correct
d += a;
d += b;
d += c;
```

And this is the final result I want

```
d = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

it would be too easy for you guys but then I am just starting with c#.

Comment: `d = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};` is not `int[]`

Comment: Shall `d` be a *jagged* array, i.e. array of array `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}` or just a simple **1D** one: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`?

Comment: @Roma I dont want it in one step

Comment: @Dmitry it should be jagged i.e. array of array like `code` {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want a simple **1D** array, try `SelectMany`:

```
  int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
  int[] b = { 4, 5, 6 };
  int[] c = { 7, 8, 9 };

  // d == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
  int[] d = new[] { a, b, c } // initial jagged array
    .SelectMany(item => item) // flattened
    .ToArray();               // materialized as a array
```

if you want a *jagged* array (*array of arrays*)

```
  // d == {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
  // notice the declaration - int[][] - array of arrays of int
  int[][] d = new[] { a, b, c };
```

In case you want to append arrays conditionally, not in one go, *array* is not a collection type to choose for `d`; `List<int>` or `List<int[]>` will serve better:

```
  // 1d array emulation
  List<int> d = new List<int>();
  ...
  d.AddRange(a);
  d.AddRange(b);
  d.AddRange(c);
```

Or

```
  // jagged array emulation
  List<int[]> d = new List<int[]>();
  ...
  d.Add(a); //d.Add(a.ToArray()); if you want a copy of a  
  d.Add(b);
  d.Add(c);
```

Comment: It looks like the last of those (`List<int[]>`) is what the OP needs.

Comment: sir it gives me an error `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
        an assembly reference?)`    is it in `System` namespace?

Comment: no, List<T> is in the `using System.Collections.Generic;` namespace

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your code that `d` is not a single-dimensional array, but it seems to be a jagged array (and array of arrays). If so, you can write this:

```
int[][] d = new int[][] { a, b, c };
```

If you instead want to concatenate all arrays to a new `d`, you can use:

```
int[] d = a.Concat(b).Concat(c).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sir I don't need a one liner imagine it in a for loop and one by one I want to add it

Comment: it is 1D array.

Comment: So then use the first sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
var z = new int[x.Length + y.Length];
x.CopyTo(z, 0);
y.CopyTo(z, x.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.Copy`. It copies a range of elements in one Array to another array. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
int[] b = {4,5,6};
int[] c = {7,8,9};

int[] combined = new int[a.Length + b.Length + c.Length];
Array.Copy(a, combined, a.Length);
Array.Copy(b, 0, combined, a.Length, b.Length);
Array.Copy(c, 0, combined, a.Length, b.Length, c.Length);
```